# SQL Element Comparison Issues

Tags: mysql

I'm working with a database with a hierarchy set up of FinishedProductID -> Sub-PartID -> ParentPartID -> PartDepthID, where each of these are separate columns, and where each breaks the tree down into smaller and smaller chunks.

An example might be 782931.4.2.1.5. At the bottom of each of these branches is a PartID number. What I'm trying to do is:

- If the current PartID = 710 and the next PartID = 812

  - then exclude that value.

So,

```
1 710...
2 612...
3 710...
4 812...
```

Accepts the first pair, drops the second pairing.

I've tried creating sub-queries with the values, but I would need this sub-query to repeat each time the main query would perform a comparison. I'm relatively new to SQL, so even small tips would be appreciated.

I know this question is somewhat vague, but it's the best way I can explain it.?
Again, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: A bit too vague. Edit your question and post the schema and the query you tried. Explain what you mean by "next part PartID". How is "next" determined?